# using return in If Statement Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

so i want to use a return  in a If Statement thats return in a part of the code :(
i want to check if the condition is valid in every DataGridView cells, so it will verify the first value if the condition not valid then it will  check the second value without do any action. i hope thats clear

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
                    ' ruturn here !
                    If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value = dt.Rows(0)(5) Then

                        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value += 1
                    Else
                        If i = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1 Then
                            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(i + 1, dt.Rows(i)(0), dt.Rows(i)(1), dt.Rows(i)(2), qnt, dt.Rows(i)(4), dt.Rows(i)(5))
                        Else
                            Return 'return to scan the second row ( i = 1,2,3... etc)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`Continue For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/continue-statement) instead of `Return`. So your solution looks like the following:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
    If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value = dt.Rows(0)(5) Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value += 1
    Else
        If i = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1 Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(i + 1, dt.Rows(i)(0), dt.Rows(i)(1), dt.Rows(i)(2), qnt, dt.Rows(i)(4), dt.Rows(i)(5))
        Else
            Continue For
        End If
    End If
Next
```

With `Return` you exit the whole `Function` or `Sub`. With `Continue For` you directly jump to the next item on the for loop without executing the code below the `Continue For`.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the second else will also do the job

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1 
    If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value = dt.Rows(0)(5) Then
    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value += 1
Else If i = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1 Then
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(i + 1, dt.Rows(i)(0), dt.Rows(i)(1), dt.Rows(i)(2), qnt, dt.Rows(i)(4), dt.Rows(i)(5)) 
    End If 
End If 
Next
```

While not exiting for manually the loop will continue anyway checking if i = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1

"Else continue for" doesn't do anything here